# SMTP Error, I don't know why

Tags: php, email, gmail

I really hope someone will help me with this. I don't know what would be the cause of my problem. But there is an error saying,

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mail Error - >SMTP  Error:
>   Could not connect to SMTP host.

Thank you in advance, I appreciate any help.

```
<?php
    require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet =  "utf-8";
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "kurokonobasket189@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "vanishingdrive";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = "465";

    $mail->setFrom('kurokonobasket189@gmail.com', 'Francis');
    $mail->AddAddress('astigvargas189@yahoo.com', 'Arnold');

    $mail->Subject  =  'using PHPMailer';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Body    = 'Hi there ,
                      <br />
                      this mail was sent using PHPMailer...
                      <br />
                      cheers... :)';

    if($mail->Send())
    {
        echo "Message was Successfully Send :)";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Mail Error - >".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Its obvious that it cannot connect, maybe the port is blocked? Did you check whoever is responsible for the network?

Comment: sorry, but what network? how can I check that?

Comment: Please include both file.
`require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once("class.smtp.php");`

Comment: Irfan, there is an error saying. require_once(class.phpmailer.php): failed to open stream:

Comment: I've tried putting "phpmailer" just like this. require_once(phpmailer/class.smtp.php) but it will return to the old error. :(

Comment: use this  **$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;**

Comment: Dave, in what part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download latest version from [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

and use this ;

```
<?php
   require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';                 // your domain username
$mail->Password = 'pass';                           // your address password
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Mailer');  //your domain addres
$mail->addAddress('bilisim_0@outlook.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('test@gmail.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

be sure you opened your secure setting ; 
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

also dont open this part `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` when you open the setting..

Comment: there is an error. :(
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: did you open ur setting from ur account what using address in the source ?

Comment: port : 25 not 587

Comment: i edited the code for you.. copy and paste on ur source.. also refresh ur browser and try again..after turn it ur setting, just regresh the page or close ur browser and open again..

Comment: thank you for your effort, but SMTP connect() failed again.

Comment: do you use localhost or web hosting?

Comment: I used localhost, I've also tried closing the browser.

Comment: look, after turn on ur setting, refresh the setting page (check if turn off or on), later back to localhost page and refresh page.. and try again..

Comment: wampserver or xampserver or iis ?

Comment: I used wampserver. :(

Comment: is it green or yellow or red ?

Comment: it is green. :(

Comment: bro its because of ur mail address settings.. you must check your gmail account password or username, and try another browser, first sign in ur account, later check the secure settings, also be sure you didnt enabled the part $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls' .. it must stay disabled when try again. if it stay open, your secure setting will be default again.

Comment: bro, it is now working. I changed the port to 587. but the message will go to the "sent mail". what about in the inbox? thank you btw.

Comment: ur wb bro.. inbox on what ?? its received to inbox of course.. just check it. use charset if you dont wanna see ur mails in junk mail.

Comment: to my gmail. when I refresh the page. I hope you will help me with that. :)

Comment: when I refresh, it will only send to the sent mail, not in my inbox.

Comment: bro sometime it receive late, you must wait .. we cant do anything on this.. i had same problem on my mail at begin. but later its fixed automatic.. or send me mail.. i can check for you.. animeresim@outlook.com

Comment: yeah .. ur wb .. :)